# Router.use() requires middleware function but got an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was experimenting with Express 4's new Router and was wondering how one would go about doing below...

I made a file named **app.js** under a routes folder containing, basically, this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = (function() {

    router.get('/testindex', function(req, res) {
        res.render('testindex');
    })

    return router;

})();
```

In my **server.js** file this works as expected...

```
var appRouter = require('./routes/app');
var apiRouter = require('./routes/api/v1.js');
app.use('/', appRouter);
app.use('/api/v1',apiRouter);
```

I was hoping to do something like this, but I got the error I mentioned in the title...

```
var router = {
    api: {
        v1: require('./routes/api/v1'),
        v2: (...)
    },
    app: require('./routes/app')
};

app.use('/api/v1', router.api.v1);
app.use('/api/v2', router.api.v2);
app.use('/', router.app);
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Which route is it complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to reproduce your issue, there is no problem when I remove this statement:

```
app.use('/api/v2', router.api.v2);
```

So, there is probably something wrong with the way you defined the `v2` property (which you did not flesh out in your question).

Comment: Thanks Sam. Actually, v2 is just there to communicate that I would be wanting to link in another version in similar manner. The actual code doesn't have the two lines containing v2. Since you mentioned there was no problem when it was removed then I'll go back and double-check my code and look for a missing character somewhere. I actually re-typed some of this from the source instead of copy-pasting when making it look nice.